# How do I make Intellisense sort alphabetically?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

How do I configure Intellisense to sort alphabetically in Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2019?

I don't have and don't want Resharper. But if that's the only way to get Intellisense to sort alphabetically, I might be forced to consider installing it.

So far I've:

- disabled the extension Visual Studio Intellicode.
- found nothing helpful at Menu > Edit > Intellisense > *
- found nothing helpful at Menu > Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Intellisense.
- found nothing helpful here on StackOverflow.
- found nothing helpful on Google.

Comment: Wait.. What? Your intellisense isn't in alphabetical order?

Comment: (But don't you just start typing anyway, and refine the list to only what you want? If thing you want starts with M, type a letter M. If the thing you want contains "Parse", type "Parse"..)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Visual Studio’s IntelliSense will help to let the IntelliCode suggested codes(methods, properties) to show at the very beginning of the Completion List and usually they will with a `*` mark. Following them are normal codes(methods, properties) which should be sorted alphabetically.

There are many options for changing behaviors of IntelliSense in Visual Studio, but indeed they are few. To my knowledge, there is no option to change the order of the default completion list(IntelliSense). But actually, the default order is alphabetical.

**Suggestions:**

If you installed some extensions which may affect the IntelliSense/text editor, please try to disable them(or try to run VS in [safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)), and you may see the IntelliSense sort alphabetically.

You can also try to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)(in VS Installer), or [reset VS settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings)(choose `General` on step 4) to avoid the impact from VS and related settings.

If you are still trapped by this issue, feel free to let me know, and perhaps you can share a screenshot or some steps which may be useful for me to reproduce your issue and check deeper:)